# [React][Webpack] How to show images dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

on create-react-app,

firstly, I loaded image correctly by putting image path directly in require()
like ' require('../~~~~');
it works. but I copied path value to variable and try it again
like ' require(url);
it doesn't work warning 'Cannot find module '../~~~~'

path is correct. what should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Don’t import images. Try rendering an HTML image element instead?

Comment: thanks. I used HTML image tag and moved image files to public folder. then it works. I think I can't access images in src folder. anyway it works after moving files to 'public' folder.